# Google Chrome. Click link (button) from console application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<a href="#" id="workButton0" style="margin-left: 7px;">Подсечь!</a>
```

I play the game and there is fishing. I want to make the code for chrome console to press some buttons when they appear and stop when got captcha.

I tried this:

```js
// 1
$('#workButton0').click();
$('#workButton2').click();

// 2
var items = document.getElementById('workButton0');
for (var i = 0; i => 0; i++) {
  $('workButton0').click();
}

// 3
var items = document.getElementById('workButton0');
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  items[i].click();
}
```

The first two click buttons only 1 times. When I tried to add loop 2) crush my page ^_^ 3) get me "Can't read null value."

Images of some buttons:
[Fishing button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU9bm.jpg)

[Strike button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSp1j.jpg)

[Button I need on the left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agcMy.jpg)

[Button I need on the right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYNNQ.jpg)

Comment: I edited your question but I still can't make sense of it. Please explain what you want to do.

Comment: I just want to click that two button. And the first button I need to click only 1 time at the beginning. And second all the time it appears.

Comment: So your if loop in 2? Where you check if i is greater than or equal to 0? Yeah, your comparator is backwards.  `=>` is referred to as a 'fat arrow' in JS, while `>=` is the greater than or equal comparator.

Answer (score 0):

In the second code snippet you make a frequent error which is the loop will run forever

If you look inside the loop , your condition says

> run this code if i greater than zero

this condition will always be true , because you add 1 to i

```
i++ ;
```

so **i** will always greater than zero 
that's why the page will crush

---

also note :-  **getElementById** only return one element and so you can not use index with it as its only one node 
so you  will get the erro 
 **Can't read null value**

a simple solution to your problem something like this

> add the same class to every button for example click-btn
>   now you can use **jquery** to click every button in the console

```
$('button').click() // click every button
$('click-btn').click() // click button has class named 'click-btn' ;
```

this will iterate over every element has the class **click-btn** and click it.

Comment: Actually, he seems to say "if  i is a function 0", does he not? `=>` is the arrow function in ES6.

Comment: I realized one more trouble. The button I need change it places from left to right and changes it ID. I added two new screens. Maybe I need catch it via text?

Comment: This two doesn't work. And I need click on special button